# Didnt return HttpResponse object. It returned None instead - django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am getting an error with a view that i have and i was wondering if anyone can help me figure out where it is coming from. I am pretty sure it is something small that I am not seeing where it is coming from...

Within the view there will be a form that is displayed for the user to input informaiton, once the form is submitted, it is processed and then redirect to the users home...

Here is the error:

```
ValueError at /transfer/
The view tab.views.transfers didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/transfer/
Django Version: 1.8.6
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view tab.views.transfers didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

Here is the views.py

```
def transfers(request):
    if 'username' not in request.session:
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        username = request.session['username']
        currentUser = User.objects.get(username = username)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TransferForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                cd = form.cleaned_data
                from_acct = cd['from_acct']
                to_acct = cd['to_acct']
                amount = cd['amount']
                memo = cd['memo']
                new_transfer = Transfers.objects.create(
                    user = currentUser,
                    from_acct = from_acct,
                    to_acct = to_acct,
                    amount = amount,
                    memo = memo,
                    frequency = 1,
                    status = 1,
                )
                return redirect('home_page')
        else:
            form = TransferForm()
            form.fields['from_acct'].queryset = Accounts.objects.filter(user = currentUser).all()
            message = 'please fill out the below form'
            parameters = {
                'form':form,
                'currentUser':currentUser,
                'message':message,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/user_balance.html', parameters)
```

Here is the html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Transfer Money</h1>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the forms.py file portion

```
class TransferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    acct_choices = (('tabz', 'Tabz - Username'),
                    ('Wells Fargo', 'Wells Fargo - Username'))
    from_acct = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=acct_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=int
    )
    to_acct = forms.TypedChoiceField(
        choices=acct_choices, widget=forms.RadioSelect, coerce=int
    )
    class Meta:
        model = Transfers
        fields = ['from_acct', 'to_acct', 'amount', 'memo']
        labels = {
            'from_acct':'from',
            'to_acct':'to',
        }
```

Comment: use HttpResponseRedirect instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TransferForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('home'))
        else:
            form.fields['from_acct'].queryset = Accounts.objects.filter(user = currentUser).all()
            message = 'please fill out the below form'
            parameters = {
            'form':form,
            'currentUser':currentUser,
            'message':message,
            }
            return render(request, 'tabs/user_balance.html', parameters)
```

html add form.errors

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Transfer Money</h1>
  {% if message %}
    <p>{{message}}</p>
  {% endif %}
  <form action='your_url/' method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: with the http response form errors, I am getting this on the screen... which means the issue is with these two fields `from_acctto_acct`   - I am going to update the question with the forms.py portion

Comment: all of the form information is being returned so i am not sure where the error is coming from. is it coming from the object that is being created.... here is what is being sent back with the form.. `
Variable Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'boNYsi6OfIlKLYUBLNiYAXOW4KChaTvf'
from_acct 
'Wells Fargo'
to_acct 
'tabz'
amount 
'200.00'
memo 
'hello memo'
submit 
'submit'`

Comment: I found out the the form cant be processed because the form is not being valid

Comment: i dont think the form is being invalid because of the response sent... it is the two fields, but how do i fix this issue with the two fields

Comment: print the errors with form.errors.as_text() and modify what's in errors

Comment: `* account * Select a valid choice. tabz is not one of the available choices. * transfer * Select a valid choice. Wells Fargo is not one of the available choices.` this is the error. If you look at the forms.py section, the choices are valid... unless there is something wrong with the error that is being displayed... if you know how to fix it can you make it an answer so i can upvote it so people know that the error was fixed

Comment: i think it's something wrong with your choice, try change to `acct_choices = ((1, 'Tabz - Username'),
                    (2, 'Wells Fargo - Username'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153580/discussion-between-omar-jandali-and-ykh).

Answer (score 1):

Well, this error should be thrown simply because you are giving an invalid form to your view. If you look at the logic of the view, if it is a POST and form is not valid the view does not return anything...  well None for python. That's the error you are getting right?
Try to put an else statement with return after `return redirect('home_page')` and see if this fixes this part.